# How to combine multiple VUnit run.py files into a single VUnit run?

Tags: python, vhdl, vunit

I have a directory and file structure like this:

```
vunit_multi/
    alfa/
        run.py
        ...
    bravo/
        run.py
        ...
```

The VUnit `run.py` can run separately.

Is there any nice way to combine these multiple separate VUnit runs into a single run with a combined status report?

Comment: This is probably better asked on VUnit's Gitter channel, which is linked from their site on Github. It's a very good support channel.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Thanks, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Please report your solution as a self answers if the VUnit team could help you out.

Comment: @Paebbels: Will do that when I get to dig further into this; for now I made a quick work around with an additional Python script calling VUnit for each test bench.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say your alfa and bravo run scripts looks something like this

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from vunit import VUnit

prj = VUnit.from_argv()

root = dirname(__file__)
lib = prj.add_library("alfa_lib")
lib.add_source_files(join(root, "*.vhd"))

prj.main()
```

Now arrange your script to this

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from vunit import VUnit

def create_test_suite(prj):
    root = dirname(__file__)
    lib = prj.add_library("alfa_lib")
    lib.add_source_files(join(root, "*.vhd"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prj = VUnit.from_argv()
    create_test_suite(prj)
    prj.main()
```

The if statement at the bottom means that the last three lines are executed if the file is called as a script (so you can still use it to test alfa) but not if the file is imported as a module into another script.

Now put a new run script like this in the top-level directory (`vunit_multi`)

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from vunit import VUnit
from glob import glob
import imp

def create_test_suites(prj):
    root = dirname(__file__)
    run_scripts = glob(join(root, "*", "run.py"))

    for run_script in run_scripts:
        file_handle, path_name, description = imp.find_module("run", [dirname(run_script)])
        run = imp.load_module("run", file_handle, path_name, description)
        run.create_test_suite(prj)
        file_handle.close()

prj = VUnit.from_argv()
create_test_suites(prj)
prj.main()
```

`create_test_suites` will find all run scripts and then iterate over those scripts. Each script file will be imported as a module to get access to the `create_test_suite` function. The function is called with the `prj` created in this top-level script to add the libraries and files specified for the module.

Now if you run the top-level script it will see all module testbenches.

Note: There are newer modules than `imp` that you can use but `imp` also works in older Python versions.

Comment: To expand on the note about `imp` at the bottom of your answer, the preferred module to use for Python 3.4+ is `importlib` 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib

Comment: How can I do this in python 3.6?